# Font-Awesome does not show on any browser don't know why?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome

I don't know but Font-Awesome does not work on any browser, tried Chrome, Mozilla, Blisk. don't know what's wrong. I tried to check the code but didn't find anything.[Here is an image for a button with fa fa-thumbs-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4E1bM.png)

Here is what I have in my code

```
<link href="font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Then I did the button and added the font-awesome thumbs-up

```
<button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Like <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up></i></button>
```

And it does show what is in the provided image don't know what's wrong.

Comment: That's a link to a local file. You need to file in the same directory as the HTML file in order for it to resolve it correctly.

Comment: most likely the filepath for your `font-awesome.min.css` isn't correct: Is that file really in the same folder as your page?

Answer (score 0):

Have you hosted font awesome? I suggest you use the CDN like this.

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```